# How to add middleware in the client side in Next.js using nextAuth

Tags: authentication, session, next.js, next-auth

```
-pages
-----admin
+++++++++index.js
```

How to create a middleware so that if user is not logged in to be redirected in a page?

Answer (score 1):

At the admin folder, you create a file "_middleware.js".

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";

export async function middleware(req, res) {
  const secret_key = process.env.SECRET_KEY;

  if (!secret_key) {
    return new Response("Blocked for Server Problems", { status: 451 });
  }

  const session = await getToken({ req, secret: secret_key });

  if (!session) {
    return NextResponse.redirect("/api/auth/signin");
  }
  return NextResponse.next();
}
```